# Disappearing/re-appearing JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm using Angular, and have a JSON response where one of the property values is disappearing (is empty), but if you look at it directly, it appears (and has the proper values). The property that is supposed to have data is the `vehicles` property.

**The JSON data**

```
{
    "data": {
        "blocks": [
            {
                "vehicles": [
                    {
                        "agency": "ZGM Bike Share",
                        "mode": "bikeshare",
                        "name": "Research Chemistry Lab",
                        "space_count": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "agency": "ZGM Bike Share",
                        "mode": "bikeshare",
                        "name": "ENG North",
                        "space_count": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "agency": "ZGM Bike Share",
                        "mode": "bikeshare",
                        "name": "Research South",
                        "space_count": 6
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "screen": {}
    }
}
```

**The console**

Below are 2 `console.log()` from this. One is the full response, and the other is accessing the `vehicles` property directly. As you can see, in the full response, it is empty, but when accessed directly it contains data.

[image: console]

**The problem**

We are using Angular and after some JS manipulation, which happens after the `console.log()` above, we are passing this object to a template. Because it's being passed as a full object, it passes it with `vehicles` empty.

**The code snippet**

This is the part that makes the call and handles the response.

```
tsApp.service('updateService', function($http, $q, jsonResponse, $timeout, $interval, $log, $location) {

  // Cut out a bunch of code that happens after getUpdate()

  function getUpdate() {
    var request = $http({
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/data/' + id + '.json',
      timeout: updateRequestTimeout
    });

    return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
  }

  function handleSuccess(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log(response.data.data.blocks[0].vehicles);
      return response.data;
  }

  return updateService;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I understand the following from your question:

You requested a resource from a remote server, got it, but the angular service returns nothing when its being called from a controller etc.

The problem is, that you initiated the request itself, and you returned the value of the handleSuccess function to the service itself, not to the caller of it.

Here's the fixed code:

```
tsApp.service('updateService', function($http, $q, jsonResponse, $timeout, $interval, $log, $location) {

  var serviceObj = { vehicles: [] };
  // Cut out a bunch of code that happens after getUpdate()

  function getUpdate() {
    var request = $http({
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/data/' + id + '.json',
      timeout: updateRequestTimeout
    });

    request.then(handleSuccess, handleError);
  }

  function handleSuccess(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log(response.data.data.blocks[0].vehicles);
      serviceObj.vehicles = response.data.data.blocks[0].vehicles;
  }

  return serviceObj;

});
```

Now, when you will need the vehicles object, you will call:

```
updateService.vehicles
```

Note that it will be empty until the response retrieved. To make sure you got it before you use it, you can also add a broadcast event on the rootScope. That way, the controller / directive that want to use it, will be able to determine if its already sent:

```
// Broadcast the handleSuccess event
serviceObj.ready = true;
$rootScope.$boradcast("updateService.vehicles.success", true);

// Listen to this event from other controller / directive to make sure the request finished up
if(updateService.ready === true) {
    successFunc()
}
$rootScope.$on("updateService.vehicles.success", successFunc);
```